# gte on string date of format yyyy--mm-dd in mongodb from loopback

Tags: mongodb, loopback

I am using mongodb with loopback . In mongodb date are saved in string of format 'yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s'. I have written query where i want all documents updated after a give date, so my query is:

Mymodel.find({where:{and:[{"status":"A"},{"updatedDate:{"gte":"yyyy-MM-dd"}}]}}).

But it return 0 zero records.
 if possible please tell me where things are wrong.

Comment: is the field "updatedDate" has a date type ? can you please print your model ?

Comment: @AnouarKacem -No its not date type, its string type.So I have to convert string type to date type then only gte or lte work?

Comment: yes you need to convert it to date type it works for me with date type hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> loopback-connector-mongodb do not support $gte or $lte by date.

I would suggest you to use regex to check of the field is a date or not or even convert the date field to epoch time and then use the comparison .

Check these issues on Github it might help .

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/176
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/303